# PayPal sandbox API credentials missing?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am using PayPal classic API. When I try to reach out for the sandbox test account API credentials, I got the empty screen below. Can anyone tell me what is going on?

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Finally I succeeded ¡¡¡¡¡¡ This works ;)

1. Log out Paypal account
2. clearing browser cache and cookies (I use firefox).
3. Go to developer.paypal.com and login with the real paypal account (not the Sandbox one)
4. Go to Applications
5. Click on *Sandbox accounts*
6. (Optional) Import your old accounts from your former Sandbox account after the redirect to the accounts page
7. Create a test account if one doesn't already exist
8. Click link *Enter Sandbox site*
9. Log in to that site using your test business account
10. Go to *Profile* -> *My Selling Tools* -> *API Access*
11. Click to Request *API Credentials*
12. Choose the option that solves your needs
13. The API credentials were created !!! (they will appear in your test account profile)

Comment: clearing cookies ftw.. Was doing all the steps except cookie removal.

Comment: You don't need to clear cache or cookies. It works on chrome without doing that. Just remember to add a real email address and verify the account.

Comment: Apparently, you need to use a sandbox account that has the same e-mail than a real account. Otherwise you'll get a warning claiming that you need to validate the e-mail before getting your API credentials (and of course there's no way to validate an e-mail in a sandbox account).

Comment: I didn't need to clear cookies, but the whole logging into the test business account on the sandbox site and requesting the credentials is the step I missed out.

Comment: I can confirm that you can't confirm an email. so thanks for the tip that you need to create an account with the same email. Of course if the account is already created you should be able to switch the email.

Comment: same STEPS follow but issue "This transaction cannot be processed due to an invalid merchant configuration" generate in opencart paypal pro

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with the Credentials not appearing for some accounts.  Currently you are logged into the developer account.  Try logging into the actual sandbox seller account, and going to the profile and requesting the credentials.  You should be able to view these from within the Sandbox seller account, and if they have not been requested yet, you can generate these.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Get a page with literally just "Please login to use the PayPal Sandbox features." I've logged in and out several times. Using Chrome incognito.

Answer (score 0):

I just went through this trouble. Such a long process (as mentioned by user2183113) is not needed at all. What you need to do is request API credentials by logging into the sandbox account for which you want to get API access. After logging in, go to "My account" and look for "API Access / Credentials" and follow the directions to request them - done!

Please note: you should first login to Paypal developer site using your regular Paypal login. Then visit www.sandbox.paypal.com and login using your dummy sandbox account and then request credentials.

Answer (score 0):

user2183113's steps didn't work for me - I couldn't find the API credential link.

I ended up just creating a new business account in Sandbox using the same email I used in 'normal paypal', this new Sandbox account comes with its own API credentials already.